# why doesn't valgrind detect excess elements in arrays

Tags: c, valgrind, memory-leaks, buffer-overflow

I am learning C and going through a tutorial that includes the use of valgrind. I am still learning about what valgrind is actually doing and was wondering if someone could explain why it does not detect any errors in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    int numbers[4] = {0,1,2,3,4};

    // first, print them out raw
    printf("numbers: %d %d %d %d %d\n",
           numbers[0], numbers[1],
           numbers[2], numbers[3],
           numbers[4]);

    return 0;
}
```

I do get compiler errors:

```
greggery@Lubu:~/code$ make lc
cc -Wall -g    lc.c   -o lc
lc.c: In function ‘main’:
lc.c:5:2: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
lc.c:5:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘numbers’) [enabled by default]
```

But when I run it against valgrind it doesn't see anything wrong:

```
==2300== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2300== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2300== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2300== Command: ./lc
==2300== 
numbers: 0 1 2 3 69156864
==2300== 
==2300== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2300==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2300==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==2300== 
==2300== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2300== 
==2300== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2300== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Isn't there a memory issue here because I am adding an extra element to the array? I thought valgrind would find a problem with the last element because it is outside the array.

Comment: And how is it possible to detect this in runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `array` is stored in `stack area` and `Valgrind` checks for the leak in `heap` area.It check for leak of memory allocated  by `dynamic allocation` so you are not getting any detection by `Valgrind`.

If you really want to see the effect then use bellow code

```
int main()
{
  int *p=malloc(6);
}
```

and use `Valgrind` to check the memory leak.

Comment: If this does the answer you can click it for answer.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [valgrind docs](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.overruns). It's an answer to a question named *Why doesn't Memcheck find the array overruns in this program?*

> > Unfortunately, Memcheck doesn't do bounds checking on global or stack arrays. We'd like to, but it's just not possible to do in a reasonable way that fits with how Memcheck works. Sorry.
> >
> > However, the experimental tool SGcheck can detect errors like this. Run Valgrind with the --tool=exp-sgcheck option to try it, but be aware that it is not as robust as Memcheck.